# XSLT: Checking if attribute exists

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to build an XSLT file to:

1. check if a node exists, and if it doesn't to fill it in with a "0"
2. if the node does exists, check to make sure each attribute is present, and if there's a missing attribute fill it in with a "0"

I figured I can do this with a `<xsl:if/>` but I'd like to avoid this because there's around 56 attributes I'd have to check for.

Here's what the main XML looks like:

```
<player name="KLINE, Zach" shortname="KLINE, Zach" checkname="KLINE,ZACH" uni="1Q" class="SR" gp="1" code="1Q">
    <rush att="1" yds="11" gain="11" loss="0" td="0" long="11"></rush>
    <pass comp="7" att="11" int="1" yds="110" td="0" long="32" sacks="0" sackyds="0"></pass>
</player>
<player name="JORDAN, Jamire" shortname="JORDAN, Jamire" checkname="JORDAN,JAMIRE" uni="1" class="SO" gp="1" code="1">
    <rush att="1" yds="1" gain="1" loss="0" td="0" long="1"></rush>
    <rcv no="5" yds="52" td="0" long="16"></rcv>
</player>
```

The output should look like this:

```
<player name="KLINE, Zach" shortname="KLINE, Zach" checkname="KLINE,ZACH" uni="1Q" class="SR" gp="1" code="1Q">
    <rush att="1" yds="11" gain="11" loss="0" td="0" long="11"></rush>
    <pass comp="7" att="11" int="1" yds="110" td="0" long="32" sacks="0" sackyds="0"></pass>
    <rcv no="0" yds="0" td="0" long="0"></rcv>
</player>
<player name="JORDAN, Jamire" shortname="JORDAN, Jamire" checkname="JORDAN,JAMIRE" uni="1" class="SO" gp="1" code="1">
    <rush att="1" yds="1" gain="1" loss="0" td="0" long="1"></rush>
    <pass comp="0" att="0" int="0" yds="0" td="0" long="0" sacks="0" sackyds="0"></pass>
    <rcv no="5" yds="52" td="0" long="16"></rcv>
</player>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an ideal case to use [**`xsl:attribute-set`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#attribute-sets). Consider the following simplified example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <player name="KLINE, Zach">
        <rush att="1" yds="11" gain="11"/>
    </player>
    <player name="JORDAN, Jamire">
        <rcv yds="52" long="16"/>
    </player>
    <player name="SMITH, Adam"/>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:attribute-set name="rush">
    <xsl:attribute name="att">0</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="yds">0</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="gain">0</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="loss">0</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="td">0</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="long">0</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<xsl:attribute-set name="rcv">
    <xsl:attribute name="no">0</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="yds">0</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="td">0</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="long">0</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="player">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <rush xsl:use-attribute-sets="rush">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rush/@*"/>
        </rush>
        <rcv xsl:use-attribute-sets="rcv">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rcv/@*"/>
        </rcv>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <player name="KLINE, Zach">
    <rush att="1" yds="11" gain="11" loss="0" td="0" long="0"/>
    <rcv no="0" yds="0" td="0" long="0"/>
  </player>
  <player name="JORDAN, Jamire">
    <rush att="0" yds="0" gain="0" loss="0" td="0" long="0"/>
    <rcv no="0" yds="52" td="0" long="16"/>
  </player>
  <player name="SMITH, Adam">
    <rush att="0" yds="0" gain="0" loss="0" td="0" long="0"/>
    <rcv no="0" yds="0" td="0" long="0"/>
  </player>
</root>
```